# scp permission error

Tags: linux, permissions, ssh, file-permissions, scp

I am trying to do a scp from a server where the user home directory has been given permission 744 recursively.
On doing scp I am getting the following error "C0744 1733 database.cpp" .

The situation did not change for a permission of 777 too. With that I am getting a similar error like "C0777 1733 database.cpp". I used the command `chmod -R ugo+rwx home-directory`.

Is there something I am missing here. I deleted the .ssh folder in the home-directory but the problem persisted.

Some additional hints:

1. To my surprise, a reverse scp i.e. scp from the server to local machine is working correctly.
2. `ssh-copy-id` on the server is also not working.

Comment: Which user account you use for scp, owner?

Comment: yes i am using the owner account.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you're trying to copy the contents of a user's home directory.

For a directory with a *mode* of 744 the owner can do anything but no one else can access it because directories have to be executable to traverse of even list the contents.

You `chmod ugo+rwx home-directory` will won't help because you didn't tell it to be recursive.  Use `chmod -R ugo+rwx home-directory`.

Comment: @above sorry I did not mention it but i had used recursive chmod. its edited now. One more thing : I am using the same user-id to copy the contents. So permission = 4/0/anything should not matter I guess.